# Change color of parts of image with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

i have a PNG image, with two colors (eg: red and blue), with javascript or html5 is possible do change de color red for yellow and the blue for green or other?

Comment: Have you looked at HTML5 Canvas?

Answer (score 4):

I've created a fiddle for presentation: **http://jsfiddle.net/tyduD/1/**

Practically you can change every color, but first you need to obtain the pixel values for each  pixel in the three main color channels (plus alpha channel, but this is not so important, but you need to take into account when you are looping over data channels). There are separate data channels for all the three color component (`RGB`).

First you need to get reference to the canvas context, then assign the data property to the pixel array which will store the pixels color values:

```
var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
var data = imageData.data;
```

With a double loop you iterate through the color channels and here you make the pixel manipulation.

```
for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        var index = (x + width * y) * 4;
        data[index+0] = data[index+2];
        data[index+1] = 255 - data[index+1];
        data[index+2] = 255 - data[index-1];

    }
}
```

Here is a great resource for working with canvas and pixel manipulation:
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/#pixelbasedmanipulation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.

First you must get the imageData of the image :

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.getElementById('myimg');
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0 );
var myData = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
```

Then you simply have to change values at `myData[i]` (for red) and `myData[i+2]` (for blue) for each `i` in the image.

And you finish by putting the imageData back in the canvas using  `context.putImageData`.

See this reference : [Pixel manipulation with canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas)

Comment: You should note that `getImageData` will only function if the image is within the same domain as the site.

Comment: Of course, but you can't even read the content of the image if it comes from another domain.

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing there. You can still draw images from external domains, but you can't get the content (thus `getImageData` doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, we agree. What I wanted to point is that if the image comes from another domain, there is exactly zero solution, even with other technologies than getImageData (apart by lowering the security level of the browser).